# how to bring this text "/\" to regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string that possibly contains the substring `/\`. How can I replace this substring with `/\\\` in perl? I tried the following:

```
$string =~ s/\\/\\/g;
```

This did not work.

Comment: Have you read your question ? It's unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:
`s/\/\\/\/\\\\/g`

\ is the escape character. if you want to use it on its own, you must escape itself by using \.

Comment: In these cases, it's much clearer to use a delimiter other than "/". For example: `s#/\\#/\\\\#g` or `s(/\\)(/\\\\)g`.

Answer (score 2):

You want to escape all occurrences of `\` to `\\` so that `(abc/\ABC)` becomes `(abc/\\ABC)`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my $str = '(abc/\ABC)';
$str =~ s:\\:\\\\:g;

print "$str\n";
# => (abc/\\ABC)
```

The example uses substitution delimiter `:` instead of `/` to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $str = '/\\';
print $str."\n";
$str =~ s!/\\!/\\\\\\!;
print $str."\n";
```